# how to convert the thymeleaf html to pdf containing google chart?

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to create a PDF version of the Thymeleaf HTML page, which includes a Google Chart to create charts in the script area. I can view the chart in the browser because the browser loaded the javascript, but when I converted it to a pdf, I only got the title; the chart was not included.
Can somebody assist me?

I've tried using Itext to convert to PDF and the system's template engine to transform HTML incorporating Google Charts into PDFs.